# Sublime Text Anaconda Invalid Syntax

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

I'm getting an Invalid Syntax Error at line 4 using @ operator:

```
from numpy import array
a = array([1, 2, 3, 4])
b = array([5, 6, 7, 8])
c = a @ b
```

But the code works. How do I fix/ignore this error settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your Anaconda doesn't know you're using `python3.5`, assuming `python2` apparently, so this syntax is invalid. You can use `set interpreter` command to set it to python3.5. You can also set it in configuration to persist setting

Comment: I spend my time with this issue not so long ago (syntax error on `async`/`await`)